# Injecting the servlet filter to the spring managed context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, spring-filter

I am using a external jar where we had a servlet filter which is not spring managed. My application is built on spring boot **how do I register servlet filter(TestHeaderFilter) to spring boot context** so that it can be intercepted whenever any http call happen.  I have two filter in my spring boot application one is using Spring WebFilter which is intercepting call currently  but another filter(Servlet filter inside jar) tried register through **FilterRegistrationBean** is not intercepting call how do i register this servlet filter so that it intercept call before **IdentityFilter**

Class which is inside jar and can't be modifiable and dependency used in this class are annotated with @component so dependency are spring managed

```
@Slf4j
@Order
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestHeaderFilter implements Filter {

  private  IdGenerator idGnerator;

  private IdSpanGenerator idSpanGenerator;
  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response,
      final FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    chain.doFilter(modifiedRequest, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {

  }
}
```

Class which I tried registering (TestHeaderFilter) through FilterRegistrationBean   but seems not working

```
 @Configuration
    public class TelemetryConfig {
    
        private  IdGenerator idGnerator;
        
        private IdSpanGenerator idSpanGenerator;
          
        @Bean("idGnerator")
        @Lazy
        @Primary
        public IdGenerator idGnerator(){
            return new IdGenerator();
        }
    
        @Bean("idSpanGenerator")
        @Lazy
        @Primary
        public IdSpanGenerator idSpanGenerator(){
            return new IdSpanGenerator();
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean<TestHeaderFilter> traceIdHeaderFilterRegistrationBean() {
            FilterRegistrationBean<TestHeaderFilter > registrationBean
                    = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    
            registrationBean
                    .setFilter(new TestHeaderFilter(idGnerato(), idSpanGenerator()));
            registrationBean.setOrder(-1);
            registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/");
    
            return registrationBean;
        }
    }
```

This identity filter is working fine and intercepting the http call

```
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;


@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class IdentityFilter implements WebFilter {



    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        if (isWhiteListedPath(serverWebExchange))
            return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);

        List<String> headers = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("Authorization");
        Optional<String> authToken = headers != null && headers.size() > 0 ? Optional.of(headers.get(0)) :
                Optional.empty();
        if (authToken.isPresent() && (authToken.get().contains("Bearer") || authToken.get().contains("bearer"))) {
            return validateToken(serverWebExchange, webFilterChain, authToken.get().substring(7));
        } else {
            return onAuthirzation(serverWebExchange, "Request doesn't have Auth token");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you’re using Spring MVC? I’ve just noticed that you seem to be using some reactive web (Spring WebFlux) classes  and you can’t mix the two.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson yes in project we are using spring web flux reactive programing . We need to integrate one internal library for logging which is using Filter is there any way to integrate with reactive

Comment: No, I’m afraid not. You cannot mix Servlet and reactive web in the same application.

Comment: thanks for guidance I was stuck whole day in same problem btw just check with including spring web starter and sample class using @RestController its working but with Reactive Router function its not working . Many thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The URL pattern of your filter registration (`registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/");`) means that the filter will only be invoked for requests to `/` and not to anything else. You probably want to use `/*` instead.

`/*` is the default so you should be able to fix your problem by removing the line that adds the url patten.

Comment: I tried /* its not working only Identity filter is invoking but  TestHeaderFilter  not